# Retrieve contacts from android only where phone number consists 123 in it

Tags: android, android-sqlite, contactscontract

I am trying to work on a project where I require all contacts of a phone which has 123 in its phone number. I am able to retrieve the contacts but "where" clause in contentresolver isn't working here's my code for reference

```
public void fetchContacts() {

        String phoneNumber = null;
        String email = null;

        Uri CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        String _ID = ContactsContract.Contacts._ID;
        String DISPLAY_NAME = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;
        String HAS_PHONE_NUMBER = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER;

        Uri PhoneCONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
        String Phone_CONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID;
        String NUMBER = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER;



        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        // Loop for every contact in the phone
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                String contact_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( _ID ));
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( DISPLAY_NAME ));

                int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( HAS_PHONE_NUMBER )));

                if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {

                    output.append("\n First Name:" + name);

                    // Query and loop for every phone number of the contact
                    Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(PhoneCONTENT_URI, null,  NUMBER + " = 123", null, null);

                    while (phoneCursor.moveToNext())

                    {

                        phoneNumber = cursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(NUMBER));
//
                        output.append("\n Phone number:" + phoneNumber);


                    }



                    phoneCursor.close();



                }

                output.append("\n");
            }

            outputText.setText(output);
        }
    }


}
```

LOGCAT
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gamemyworldgame.contact/com.gamemyworldgame.contact.MainActivity}:
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                                            **Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: phone.NUMBER (code 1): ,**

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your query -

```
Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,  "ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER like '%123%'", null, null);
```

This will fetch you all those phone number which have '123' anywhere in that number.

Another way -

```
final String keyword = "%123%"; // contains an "123"

Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + " LIKE ?", new String[] { keyword }, null);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, using this lines app is not starting and is throwing error in logcat

Comment: You should use Phone.NUMBER instead of NUMBER. Updated the answer.

Comment: I have updated my question with logcat error please do help

Comment: You used "phone.NUMBER". The column should be "Phone.NUMBER" .

Comment: Still almost same locat no such column Phone.NUMBER(code1)

Comment: error :Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 51 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

Comment: This means your query is working fine.You just have to fetch the values correctly. Debug if the control goes inside the while loop after query(). If it is then the issue is with how you are fetching the values from the cursor.

Comment: I solved the error but it is showing all the contacts also the one that does not contain 123,  using your 2nd query

Comment: while (phoneCursor.moveToNext())

                    {

                        phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(NUMBER));
                        output.append("\n Phone number:" + phoneNumber);


                    }